# UWP - GridView : how to add an "Add" button after the last item?

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp, addition, datatemplateselector

I use a GridView to display photos and I search an elegant way to allow user to add a new item to a form.

- The form contains a lot of fields: it is displayed in a Pivot, where each PivotItem represents a category of the form.
- Some categories contain one or more child items: they are displayed through a Master-Detail page.

It's in this page that I need to display a list of photos: as a photo represents a "sub sub item" of the form, I wouldn't manage the add of a new photo through the CommandBar. But I would like to use an "Add" button after the last item of the GridView containing the photos.

At this time I only found a solution that partially work:
[image]

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock Text="Photos"  Grid.Row="0"/>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding images}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" 
                        Padding="10"
                        Height="150" Width="190">
                    <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"
                           Source="{Binding bitmap_image}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" 
            Padding="10"
            Height="150" Width="190">
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddPhotoCommand, ElementName=DetailsPage}"
                Height="100" Width="100">
            <Viewbox>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Add"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Button>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

As I use a StackPanel, the Add button is no longer visible if I display 3 photos...

***=> Is there a better way to do this? Or do you see a an alternative? I'm looking for doing this through a DataTemplateSelector, but that would require me to create a "false" object for displaying the add button...***

Comment: I'd go for a DataTemplateSelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I use a StackPanel, the Add button is no longer visible if I display 3 photos...

If you don't mind the button is in the next line of your last photo, you can use [WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit)'s `WrapPanel` instead of `StackPanel` to avoid the pictures goes out of the window and put the button inside the `GridView`'s `FooterTemplate`:

Xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="AddButtonSample.MainPage"
xmlns:controls="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
...
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Photos"  Grid.Row="0"/>
    <controls:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding images}">
            <GridView.FooterTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=AddPhotoCommand}" Height="100" Width="100">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Add"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.FooterTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" 
                    Padding="10"
                    Height="150" Width="190">
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"
                       Source="{Binding bitmap_image}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </controls:WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Result:
[image]

If you really want to put the Button side by side after the last item of `GridView`. The only Option is `DataTemplateSelector`.

Comment: Thanks for you return!
I've tried to implement your solution but I meet a binding problem, as the ContentPresenter that I use to display the Detail is bonded directly to the Model: I don't see how to bind the button to the main ViewModel, whereas other form's fields bind well on this ViewModel.

I create a new topic about this point:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835301/uwp-how-to-bind-a-contentpresenters-element-to-the-main-viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

The best solution might be to use a `CommandBar` and put the "Add" button in the very bottom of the panel, as that would be most consistent with UWP design guidelines. `GridView` also has a `FooterTemplate`, which allows you to add some XAML in the footer of the whole `GridView` (but not directly after the items).

If you still want to have the add item as part of the `GridView` contents, you will really need to use the fake item and a `DataTemplateSelector`. This solution is not very clean, but probably is the only simple way.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about the use of "Add" button in bottom of the CommandBar's panel: do you have a link or a sample?
I will purpose the 3 possibilities to my client at the next meeting.

Comment: I missed the fact that the `GridView` is basically a sub-sub component, so the `CommandBar` solution is probably not a good choice here. The `FooterTemplate` however is still feasible. You could also place an Add button to the `HeaderTemplate` of the `GridView`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something similar for my own app too, but there really isn't an obvious way to achieve it. A little background on what my app does: it's a flashcard app that displays decks of card in a gridview on the homepage, with an add button being at the front of the gridview. This is what I did:

1. for my deck class, I gave it a `bool` attribute `isButton`
2. in the observablecollection of decks, set the first item's `isButton` to `true`
3. make two datatemplates for the gridview (deck and button) and make a data template picker for the gridview, and check the `isButton` attribute
4. if `isButton` is `true`, the template picker will use the button template
5. otherwise use deck template

Comment: basically make one of the pictures a button