# UWP - How to bind a ContentPresenter's element to the main ViewModel?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, binding, uwp, viewmodel

I work on an app where the user can edit a "big" form:

- The form contains a lot of fields: it is displayed in a **Pivot**, where each **PivotItem** represents a category of the form.
- Some categories contain one or more child items: they are displayed through a **Master-Detail** presentation.

To display the items of the Detail part, I use a **ContentPresenter** that is binded directly to the Model:

```
<ContentPresenter
    x:Name="DetailContentPresenter"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    BorderThickness="1,0,0,0"
    Padding="24,0"
    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}"
    Content="{x:Bind MasterListView.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}">

    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Form_Parts">
            <...>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

This works fine, but there is a "third" level in the main form: a list of photos, that I display in the ContentPresenter through a **GridView**. This works also great, but I would like to use an "Add" button or the "ItemClick" event to interact with the photos: I don't see how I could bind a Command in the main ViewModel, instead of the ContentPresenter's DataContext. The other fields of this form bind well on this ViewModel.

I did some tests without any result:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding images}"
              ItemClick="{Binding PhotoClickCommand}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" 
                        Padding="10"
                        Height="150" Width="190">
                    <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"
                           Source="{Binding bitmap_image}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" 
            Padding="10"
            Height="150" Width="190">
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddPhotoCommand, ElementName=DetailsPage}" 
                Height="100" Width="100">
            <Viewbox>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Add"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Button>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

***=> is there a way to doing this?***

**Edit :**
I solved my problem for the "Add" button thanks Alteik with:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.AddPhotoCommand}" Height="100" Width="100">
```

But I always get a problem with the **ItemClick** of the **GridView**. I tried this:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding images}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          SelectionMode="None">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.EditPhotoCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <...>
</GridView>
```

But I don't get the expected parameter in the ViewModel:

```
private void EditPhoto(object sender)
{
    Images sImage = (Images)sender;
    if (sImage != null)
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateTo<CommentImageViewModel>(this, new Object[] { sImage }, true);
    }
}
```

The sender is the current **Form_Parts** (the DataTemplate of the ContentPresenter), whereas I would get the selected item of my images collection, that is binded to the GridView...

***=> Whad could I do to fix this?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the DataContext in a child element doing this:

```
Command"{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.TheCommandFromRoot}"
```

Obviously you need to set the name of the parent's element to "Root"

Comment: Thanks, please select the answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Comment: Yes, but I have a similar question in the same page: I need to get the clicked item of the GridView.
I tried to play with <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped"> but I don't pass the clicked item as Parameter...
Do you have an idea? Or do I need to create a new topic for this question?

Comment: Is it possible to share the ICommand implementation? maybe you're not using it right, because usually the implementation will have the CommandParameter as a parameter in the Execute method